# SQL query syntax on JIRA

Tags: sql, jira

The below query is used for  "List of users ordered by last login and include user id, email and at least one Group that they belong to" in JIRA.....

```
SELECT cu.user_name
, dateadd(second,cast(cast(cua.attribute_value as nvarchar(255)) as bigint)/1000,'19700101 00:00:00:000') 'last Login'
, cu.lower_display_name
, cu.email_address
, (SELECT MAX(parent_name) FROM [jira].[dbo].[cwd_membership] cm WHERE cm.child_name = cu.user_name AND cm.parent_name NOT IN ('jira-sysadmins','jira-administrators','jira-users','jira-developers')) 'Group'

FROM cwd_user cu INNER JOIN cwd_user_attributes cua
ON cu.id = cua.user_id
AND cua.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
AND cu.active = '1'
order by 2 desc
```

Sample Result set for Last Login

```
last Login
1/8/2014 6:43:07 PM
1/8/2014 6:23:10 PM
1/7/2014 9:11:56 PM
```

Can anyone please edit this query by adding a condition on "last Login" so that it only returns results from the past 90 days (like "last Login"> sysdate - 90)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database you're using? SqlServer?
In this case you can use DATEDIFF() function, adding the clause :
`AND DATEDIFF(GETDATE(), dateadd(second,cast(cast(cua.attribute_value as nvarchar(255)) as bigint)/1000,'19700101 00:00:00:000') < 90`

I didn't try it (no sqlserver available on my computer), but I think you're pretty close

Comment: Yes it is Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2.
I am getting this exception while executing the sql including your where clause:

"Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near '<'"

Comment: Thanks cLyric with some other tweaks ... I was able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the conversion a clean way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(

    SELECT cu.user_name
    , dateadd(second,cast(cast(cua.attribute_value as nvarchar(255)) as bigint)/1000,'19700101 00:00:00:000') AS [last Login]
    , cu.lower_display_name
    , cu.email_address
    , (SELECT MAX(parent_name) FROM [jira].[dbo].[cwd_membership] cm WHERE cm.child_name = cu.user_name AND cm.parent_name NOT IN ('jira-sysadmins','jira-administrators','jira-users','jira-developers')) 'Group'

    FROM cwd_user cu INNER JOIN cwd_user_attributes cua
    ON cu.id = cua.user_id
    AND cua.attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis'
    AND cu.active = '1'
)
WHERE [last Login] > DATEADD(day,-90,GETDATE())
order by [last login] desc
```